# Car Heating due to the sun: comparison of different contributions

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Let's imagine that we need to choose a car in order to minimize the Temperature that the inner part of the car will reach after some hours under the sun. We know that two factors (if we suppose that the glass opening are given) contribute to the final temperature:

1. the colour of the outer part of the car;
2. the colour of the interior of the car (due to the [Greenhouse effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194936/how-is-it-possible-that-it-can-get-hotter-in-the-car-than-it-is-outside?newsletter=1&nlcode=438738%7C3569));

Which one is more important? Can you estimate the two contributions $\Delta T_1$ and $\Delta T_2$ to the final stationary temperatures for an average glass opening size?

Comment: You should expand your question post with some some educated guesses as to why there might be differences in $\Delta T_1$ and $\Delta T_2$, and which might be more important. That shows us that you've put some thought into it, and we might be able to reinforce or correct some of your concepts.

Comment: Yesterday I commented to a colleague that I want to build some metal, glass, and plexiglass boxes and do this experiment.