# Heating of a closed car

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

The TV know-it-all’s keep telling us that if the air temperature is 90°F, the interior will reach 109°F in ten minutes.  Now, I’m not going to make a stink about a generalization, but I’m just **curious about how big a variation there might be**.  I presume it is affected by many things, including

- Angle of the sun
- Shadows of trees/buildings
- Time of day
- Wind
- Clouds
- Humidity
- Size, shape, orientation of car
- Paint color
- Window tint
- Window size
- Interior fabrics
- (and more)

Related: [Car Heating due to the sun: comparison of different contributions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195358/car-heating-due-to-the-sun-comparison-of-different-contributions)

Comment: The point is to make people remember that cars get hot, and they should not leave their kids in the car seat in the back when they just 'pop in' to a store to get something. It is not meant to be rigorous, but to make people realize the dangers.

Comment: I know that—I said I had no complaint with the generalization.  And “just pop in” is likely to be more than ten minutes.  But I am still curious about what I actually asked.

Comment: which TV know-it-all said this? I don't recall any. Maybe you should add a citation. @WGroleau

Comment: Does it matter?  It's been on our local station almost every day for a while.  Again, it's not important.  Just background.